# How to append a list each time to a new column of a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a `for` loop which produces a python `list` in each of it's iterations. I want to append the `list` to a new column in the CSV file in each iteration of `for` loop. The CSV file should be created at the time of writing the first `list` to it.

The code producing the lists is similar to  this code:

```
for a in range(1,10):
    b = list(range(1,a+1))
    print(b)
```

After the first iteration of the `for` loop, the CSV file should contain the first list and so on.
The CSV file after three iterations of the `for` loop should be similar to this.

```
col1   col2     col3 
1        1        1
2        2        2
3        3        3
         4        4
                  5
```

I don't necessarily want the headers for the columns.
Thank You All...

Comment: Do you want to save a new csv at each iteration?

Comment: @balandongiv no ,,, i just want to append a new column each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
import pandas as pd
for a in range(1,10):
    b = list(range(1,a+1))
    if a==1:
        df = pd.DataFrame({a:b})    

    else:
        df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({a:b}), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

When you print the df you'll get this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1
1   NaN 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2
2   NaN NaN 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3
3   NaN NaN NaN 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 6.0 6.0 6.0 6
6   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.0 7.0 7
7   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8.0 8
8   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 9
```

Comment: @AhmadFaraz Happy to help!